# mysql triggers - limiting the amount of values stored in a column

Tags: mysql, triggers

Database name: Library

```
Clients table: 
ID_number | Surname | Forename ...

Loans table: 
Loan_ID | Borrower | Book | Date
```

Clients ID_Number is a foreign key in Loans.Borrower

I want to limit the amount of loans per client to <= 5

So if in Borrower column an ID_Number repeats > 5 times do not insert.

How would I implement this using a TRIGGER?

So far I have :

```
CREATE TRIGGER limit_borrows BEFORE INSERT

ON Loans

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

[NO IDEA WHAT GOES HERE]

IF value in borrow column repeated > 5 
Do not insert

[NO IDEA WHAT GOES HERE]



END IF;

END //
```

Comment: You're obliged to use a trigger?

Comment: Yes, I was given the hint TRIGGER and told to go research.

Comment: Well, if you decide you want to do without a trigger, let me know,

Comment: That would be great. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS loans;

CREATE TABLE loans
(loan_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,user_id INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO loans (user_id) 
SELECT 128 
  FROM (SELECT 1) x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT user_id
            , COUNT(*) total 
         FROM loans 
        GROUP  
           BY user_id
     )  y 
    ON y.user_id = 128
   AND y.total >= 5
 WHERE y.user_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the number of id's in your if statement and trigger an error so that the row is not inserted:

```
CREATE TRIGGER limit_borrows BEFORE INSERT

ON Loans

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
DECLARE _id (borrower id data type here)

SELECT borrower from loans where loan_ID = new.loan_ID into _id;

SET @count = (select count(1) from loans where borrower_id = _id ;
IF @count > 5
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'your error message';

END IF;

END //
```