# How to prevent SELECT from reading a table until after another transaction is done

Tags: mysql

Here is the thing. I need to insert a row into a table but ONLY if the number of rows is less than 10.

Normally I do this by:

1. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE cDate = '2019-01-01'`;
2. Check that the return value is less than 10. If not, then I need to return a message to the user.
3. If it is less than 10. I do `INSERT INTO mytable (cDate) VALUE ('2019-01-01')`.

Now this is running in a server and the table has 9 rows. So if while I'm doing the check on the number of rows, ANOTHER user does the same check it will again return 9 rows (because the INSERT has not happened yet). This will result in two inserts giving a total of 11 rows where the maximum allowed is 10.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What DB storage engine does that table have? How do you start the transaction and how do you end it? Did you ensure that all queries belonging to on transaction are run within the same connection?

Comment: You can omit the SELECT altogether (and slightly amend the INSERT). That's one way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998314/mysql-triggers-limiting-the-amount-of-values-stored-in-a-column

Comment: @Strawberry. I'm looking at the answer but I don't understand it as more that half the keywords there I've never seen before. I was hoping for simpler solution that using BEGIN, END, DECLARE, TRIGGER which I have never used before. But I don't mind modifying the queries as long as it becomes clear that if the query fails it is because the condition is not met

Comment: @t.niese InnoDB. I don't start a trasnaction nor end it. I'm usning PHP. As I understand, everytime I execute a query it is within a transaction. As for the last question, I'm not sure, as I have never come across this problem before. This is a web server and it creates a new connection for every client. Does that answer your question?

Comment: My point is, you don't need a transaction!

Comment: @Strawberry. There was a misunderstanding. I called a transaction to the actual query. I realize now that was a poor choice of words. I'm not saying I need a transaction. I just need to make sure to avoid the situation. I understand you are suggesting I change the 2 queries into one, but the ones provided in your link I do not understand

Comment: Well, if you provide proper DDLs, I (or someone else) might be able provide a more complete answer.  [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @aarelovich one query on its own is atomic, if you have multiple dependent queries then you need to either rewrite them into one single atomic query, or you need to use transactions.

Comment: @t.niese. I have followed the answer below to write it into a single query. However this brings me another problem. When the row does not get created (due to the maximun number of rows being reached) I get no feedback. Nothing happens (which is correct) but I need to inform the user that the maximum number of rows was reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use dual :

```
INSERT INTO tReservations (cClass, cFecha, cDNI) SELECT '12','2019-11-13','30913307' FROM DUAL WHERE 12 > (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tReservations WHERE cFecha ='2019-11-13' AND cClass = '12')
```

Comment: hope it helps you !

Comment: So I've tried to use your solution but no dice. I get a syntax error. In my example the query is over simplified a bit. But I believe the problem is that the first part is incorrect when I need to insert 3 values. My actual query is: "INSERT INTO tReservations (cClass, cFecha, cDNI) SELECT ('12','2019-11-13','30913307') FROM DUAL WHERE 12 > (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tReservations WHERE cFecha ='2019-11-13' AND cClass = '12')." Which gets me the error Operand should contain 1 column(s). And I don't really understand what its talking about...

Comment: I edited the answer to fit your query just remove the () between the values and it should work fine

Comment: Thank you!! This worked! One final question, the query does not do anything if the condition of "12 >" is not met. Should I do another select just to see if the query was successull? Because I need to return some sort of feedback to the user.

Comment: Why `12`? And why in Yoda form?

Answer (score -2):

It will Works `COULMN NAMES SHOULD BE EQUAL TO SELECTED COLUMNS FROM THE DATABASE TABLE`

V means Value and C Means Column Name Where do you want to insert  data.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE NAME(C1,C2,C3,C4
            VALUES(SELECT v1,v2,v3,COUNT(*) as COUNT
                   FROM mytable
                   WHERE cDate = '2019-01-01'
                   AND COUNT >10)
```